# Deploying Datasnap Service

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-services, c++builder, datasnap

Using C++ Builder under Rad Studio XE I have created a simple Datasnap server service from scratch.  I wanted to test the service installation process before adding any functionality, and found that while it will install successfully on a range of Windows machines, I haven't been able to get it to Start under a clean installation of Windows 7 x64.

The error message trying to start the service is: Windows could not start the service on Local Computer.  Error 2: The system cannot find the specified file.

I have turned off both dynamic linking and run-time libraries.  It starts fine under Windows XP and 2003 operating systems, just not this single Win7 machine that I have.  I have opened the firewall for the specified ports, and confirmed no other app is using them as well.  The service was installed under Administrator, and logs on as Local System account.

Is there a problem with a C++ Builder compiled service under Windows 7, or maybe 64 bit?  Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction so I don't have to bang my head against the wall too many more time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++ Builder creates 32bit applications only, make sure you install the service in the c:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder on 64bit Win7 systems.  Windows 7 x64 expects to find only 64bit files/services in the system32 folder.